# rails - Dead pages on web app heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hello I am making a little quiz web app as a learning project. However when on my heroku server there are some dead pages, but not when I am running on my local server. Here is my heroku address: https://krisquiz.herokuapp.com/

The dead pages are when you submit a question and when you try and start a quiz. I looked at the urls and they look properly. The only thing in common that I can think of for the two pages is that I built the urls manually for the links (ex: request.base_url + '/quiz/' + quiz.id.to_s + '/start'). As I am not sure what I need to give you as information just tell me and I will try to quickly get back to you.

My heroku logs: http://pastebin.com/Tqfb4C6r

Comment: Check your logs `heroku logs`

Comment: sorry but I can't seem to understand what is causing the issue when I look at them

Comment: Can you please paste the logs from when the application actually blows up?

Comment: these are all of the logs